# Chrome not support box-sizing?

Tags: css

Im working on a site and im using the box sizing method to stop divs breaking size when padding is added.

I have the following...

```
-moz-box-sizing:padding-box;
box-sizing:padding-box; 
-webkit-box-sizing:padding-box;
```

Does anybody know of an issue regarding chrome supporting this?

Comment: I think you could maybe use "box-sizing: border-box;" and that should work in Chrome too.

Comment: border-box is not the same as padding-box Billy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Padding-box` isn't currently supported in chrome

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: That's because it was a late Mozilla proposal. It's also in danger of being dropped from the spec if it doesn't reach the other browsers soon, since Mozilla remains the only vendor that has implemented it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` in place of `box-sizing:padding-box;`.

`padding-box` is experimental, and includes padding size in the height and width of an element, but does not include border or margin.

`border-box;` has been around for a while and includes padding size and the border in the height and width of an element, but not the margin. It's supported by all major browsers, but does require a prefix in Firefox.  Example:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

For more, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing.